# How to modify or change the whatever controls in the adapter?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am new to `android`.
My question is if i want to do any changes or update in `Adapter`.
I am just modifying the whatever `list` is present `in  Adapter`.
and i will call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method,
then whole `Adapter` is updating.
But whenever i am updating the `Adapter` listing if i want to do  modify or change the whatever controls present in `Adapter`(means if i want to hidden some `TextView`) how i will do ? please help me 
my code for updating list

```
    customExpandableRecyclerView.projectList.clear();
    customExpandableRecyclerView.projectList = allProjectList;
    customExpandableRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: If you wish to hide/unhide some view you have to maintain some `flag` inside your `projectList model`. and based on that flag hide/unhide your view inside `onBindViewHolder`

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` only tells adapter to redraw its views again. The logical of what items have to show or hidden resides on `onBindViewHolder` method of the adapter. In this method you can implement something like this:

```
if (hasToHideTextView) {
    textview.setVisibility(View.Gone)
} else {
    textview.setVisibility(View.Visible)
}
```

Remember you have other methods for refreshing the adapter like `notifyItemChanged(position)`, `notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount)`, etc.

Comment: i will explain my problem i create one activity and one adapter class .in adapter contain two textview controls one for showing project name and second for project task count.in my activity i have 3 buttons  1.all 2.complete 3.uncomplete  so 1st  button(all) click i want show 2 controls in adapter but  2nd and 3rd button click i want show only one controls name means project name  i want hide task count

Comment: Better solution is:-
1) to have 1 method in your adapter

private Boolean firstButtonClicked = false; 
myNotifyDataSetChanged(Boolean firstButtonClicked){
   firstButtonClicked=this.firstButtonClicked;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
in your adapter with boolean true for 1st button and false for ather 2 buttons. 

2) call that adapter method myNotifyDataSetChanged(true/*false*/); from onClick of button that's in your activity.

3) In you onCreatView 
if (firstButtonClicked ) {
    textview.setVisibility(View.Gone)
} else {
    textview.setVisibility(View.Visible)
}